# Completion: Multiple similar options

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I want to write completions for a program that takes `--with-PROG=` and `--PROG-options` as optional arguments. `PROG` may be one of different programs. There are many different programs, so I'd like to avoid manually writting out an options for each program. I did try the following:

```
#compdef hello

typeset -A opt_args
local context state line

_hello()
{
    typeset -a PROGS
    PROGS=('gcc' 'make')
    _arguments \
        '--with-'${^PROGS}'[path to PROG]:executable:_files' \
        '--'${^PROGS}'-options[PROG options]:string:'
}
```

Output:

```
$ hello --gcc-options
--make-options  --gcc-options  -- PROG  options                                                                                                                          
--with-make     --with-gcc     -- path to PROG
```

However, I'd like to have each individual option on a seperate line, and also replace `PROG` with the program name. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use array holding argument to _arguments:

```
_hello()
{
    emulate -L zsh
    local -a args_args
    local prog
    for prog in gcc make ; do
        args_args+=( 
            "--with-${prog}[path to $prog]:executable:_files"
            "--${prog}-options[$prog options]:string:"
        )
    done
    _arguments $args_args
}
```